# Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: android, compiler-errors, resources

I use latest Android Studio 0.8.4 (for OS X), in "res" directory I create new "database" directory and put there all files what I need and when I try to compile I receive this error.

```
Error:Content is not allowed in prolog.
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
/Users/filipp/data/Android_dev/project/app/src/main/res/database/5clSubject0Book0.txt
Error:Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /Users/filipp/data/Android_dev/project/app/src/main/res/database/5clSubject0Book0.txt:0:0:   Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> in "res" directory I create new "database" directory

That is not supported. You cannot invent new resource directories.

Please put the files in `res/raw/` (and use via `getResources().openRawResource()`) or `assets/` (and use via `getAssets().open()`).

Comment: I don't have "raw" directory in "res" directory. Or I must create it ?

Comment: @Never_be: You must create it.

Comment: All works, but resource file cannot start from digit O_o after Xcode this Android Studio is killing me (

Comment: @Never_be: Resource names have to be valid Java data member names, and those cannot start with a number. That has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: This answer resolve my problem.
In my case, I moved all file in res/navigation at old module to new module, then res/navigation resource directory would be empty.

After I delete empty resource directory, It work. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that this can be caused by an _empty_ subfolder within res, which would otherwise be acceptable if it had xml in it.  This is especially silly given that git does not recognize empty folders as repo differences.

Answer (score 17):

I am having the same problem What I did is,

*You need to clear the cache data*

**Go to Build(Menu)--> Clean Project**

Then

**Go to Build(Menu)--> Rebuild Project**

Then Run Your project

> This may also help in refreshing data of android preview

Answer (score 13):

You might want to clean caches

```
C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\caches
```

Comment: This has solved the same problem for me, so in some cases this is an answer (for people coming here from Google).

Comment: clean is delete all content

Comment: Thank you for this.  I wasted so much time trying to fix this problem

Comment: Man, I wasted like half a day on this issue, tried so many things, but this worked like a charm, also I had this issue while making a flutter build in Android Studio

Comment: Thank you so muuuuuuuuch, i waste half a day in that problem and u solve my problem. TY

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I had accidentally entered a random character right before the beginning of my strings.xml file.

[image]

I removed the "f" character before the xml declaration and all was well again.

Comment: If it hadn't been for you, I would have never found the solution. Thanks

Comment: I remember wasting an hour trying to figure out what the heck that error meant. Glad to help

Comment: I laughed at loud when I saw that I did the same mistake. Thank you! :D

Answer (score 8):

Old question but googling the error got me here.

This was fixed for me by deleting the (empty) "navigation" folder from res, it was left over when checking out a different branch from a repository, appears it can't be empty or it will cause this error.

Comment: O.m.g. a total nonsense. This fixed my issue. God damn it. Makes no sense at all. My error was being thrown on the gradle's manifest merge task. Thanks man. Couple hours lost before I found your message

Answer (score 3):

Try the following steps

1. Go to the `Build Menu`.
2. Select the option `Clean Project`.
3. Once again, go to the `Build Menu`.
4. Select the option `Rebuild Project`.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error when I created assets folder inside app/src/main/res/

We shouldn't create folders anywhere at our will.
To create new folders, make sure that you go to
File -> Folder and  consequently ,choose one of the folders among the options displayed.
This way the IDE creates the folder at appropriate locations and thus accessing them doesn't raise any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I removed all of the compile statements. Then, I deleted the jar files from libs (and selected 'safe delete'). Once that was done, I dragged the  jar file back into libs. Once there, I right clicked on libs selected to add it as a library. Now the gradle builds fine and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have predefined set of folder inside res folder.
so you are creating database folder inside res folder which is invalid.
Either put database files inside assets folder or raw folder.

Answer (score 0):

Perform `Build Clean` and `Rebuild Project` did not work for me.

I had to manually delete `.idea/caches`, then rebuild project.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a comment `/* launch_screen.xml */` at the beginning of my launch_screen.xml file.
After removing `/* launch_screen.xml */` comment from my code I was able to solve this issue

[image: code image]