# Android Studio loading issue

Tags: android, android-studio

How to solve this issue .

**Load setting Cannot load settings from file**

> 'C:\Users\sujeet14108\AndroidStudioProjects\Rough.idea\gradle.xml':
>   Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Please correct the file content

Comment: Delete app/ **build**  folder and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because of `gradle.xml` inside `App/build` directory of your project.

### Try this way

1. Clean your project using **Build > Clean** Project
2. Close your Android Studio now
3. Go to the project directory and delete the `gradle.xml` file
4. Open Android Studio again and let it **sync the project with gradle** .

> [Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)