# Android studio 3.0 error Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/

Tags: android, android-studio

i updated my android studio 2.3.3 to 3.0 and it showed me this error. how can i fix this? please i need your help

[this picture below shows my android studio 3.0 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcHj4.png)

Comment: delete the `build` and `.gradle` not gradle folder from the project and clean project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/37480542#37480542

Comment: Check your internet connection, then try to build from terminal.

Comment: i don't know how to build with the terminal

Comment: I deleted .gradle folder and now i'm stuck in - Building 'MyApplication' Gradle Project info

Answer (score 1):

Check your Connection then try to Rebuild again or Disable Graddle Offline.