# Font Resources do not work. Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android, fonts, android-resources

I added the font file compact_bold.ttf:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0KxY.png)
An error occurs during build:

> /app/src/main/res/font/compact_bold.ttf Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   /app/src/main/res/font/compact_bold.ttf:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMw5S.png)

Comment: can you check if this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: **Wrong folder**! Try putting your fonts in `assets/fonts`

Comment: HI I am also facing the same issue. how you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use android studio 3.0+ and gradle version 4.1+ and also edit your targeted sdk version and buildtoolversion to 26+