# Weird behavior of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I upgraded the studio to 3.1.2 version lately. After that facing few issues, one of which is this :

[image: Issue]

Even though all imports are written correctly, the files are said not to be found and I get the class names in red saying "Cannot resolve symbol".

But when I try to run the project it runs perfectly. I tried to invalidate cache and restart, clean project, rebuild project, also tried restarting the PC but no solution.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100896/7746134

Comment: show gradle file

Comment: You may try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog/37480542#37480542

Comment: invalidate cache and restart your Android studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Kotlin library version and check some other version of library it might be not compatible with new android studio version and also check gradle version.