# What does word prolog in "Error: Content is not allowed in prolog." mean?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm building `ionic v.1` application, targeting `android` and seen some strange error:

> Execution failed for task ‘:mergeReleaseResources’.
>   .../cordova/project/platforms/android/**res**/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

This seems to be related to creating new folders inside **res** folder (as highlighted in the path above) that this answer suggests [Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25145706/2730688). In this specific case it's probably presence of **icon** folder, instead of/along with **icons** - that is generated by Ionic framework e.g. by running `ionic cordova resources`.

**Questions:** What does this word **prolog** mean in this context? Is there some definition (obviously there is some place that specifies what should be where) of files or structure that you need to obey?

Comment: In this context, "prolog" is a synonym for "prologue" and refers to the beginning of a file that contains invalid content.

Comment: @PauloMoura where is the validator that validates those files? The issue above is resolved when sticking to ionic convention of folders, so in this case it's not very clear how it's related to `beginning of a file that contains invalid content`.

Comment: I removed the "prolog" tag since the "prolog" tag is about the Prolog programming language, not a PNG file prolog.