# C:\Users\SABUJ\AndroidStudioProjects\new\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: android

How can i fix it??

> C:\Users\SABUJ\AndroidStudioProjects\new\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml:1:1:
>   Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

I am facing this problem when creating a new project and also when opening an existing project.

Comment: Follow that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog

Comment: How to create  "raw" directory in "res" directory Engr Waseem Arain

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSabuj1604013 follow that my answer

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** There is no pre featured option in Android for adding raw folder unlike Assets folder. Open App folder and select res folder

**Step 2:** Right click on res folder, select New> Directory, then studio will open a dialog box and it will ask you to enter the name.

[image]

**Step 3:** Write “raw” and click OK. Open res folder and you will find your raw folder under it.

[image]

Now you have created raw folder in your project.