# Running my code giving an Exception "org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException"

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

I'm unable to run my code in any of my devices. It is giving out an error:

> **org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException**:
>
> Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':networkinglib:javaPreCompileDebug' property.

What should be the issue if anyone has come across this?

I've already tried all the solutions found in stack overflow and other build variable changes, but doesn't seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Go Settings/Gradle/Android Studio. Then check "Enable embedded Maven repository".

Comment: I am getting "Content is not allowed in prolog" error in the build console.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog) may help you