# "Resource and asset merger error" - Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I tried to downgrade the **gradle version** also.

Comment: Since the error message appears below colors.xml, please copy-paste the content of colors.xml here

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0):

I also got this error and i solved this by replacing res folder.
I deleted all resource file and paste new resource file from other projects and changed them.