# I have a problem when using Firebase with Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

EDIT : I JUST REALIZED THAT IT HAPPENS EVEN WITH A SIMPLE SCREEN WITH AN APPBAR

```
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom:2:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:27.0.0
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/22.1.2/firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.

> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :cloud_firestore
> > Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2.
> > Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/22.1.2/firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom
> > Content is not allowed in prolog.
> Content is not allowed in prolog.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 19s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

//> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.

> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2. (REPETEAD MANY TIMES  )

//> Could not resolve com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:22.1.2.
> Could not parse POM https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/firebase/firebase-firestore/22.1.2/firebase-firestore-22.1.2.pom (REPETEAD MANY TIMES  )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android studio compile error "Content is not allowed in prolog"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145539/android-studio-compile-error-content-is-not-allowed-in-prolog)

Comment: Please pay attention to correct capitalisation.

Answer (score 0):

in your build.gradle,

add this

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

or you should change your sdk version  to 21 i think

Comment: means after what is there just add multidexEnabled

Comment: In wich  build.gradle and what is supposed to be where the 3 dots. Thanks

Comment: just add multidexEnabled true

Comment: Didnt Work but Thanks anyways

Comment: EDIT : I JUST REALIZED THAT IT HAPPENS EVEN WITH A SIMPLE SCREEN WITH AN APPBAR